# Find whether I am authenticated or the XMLHttpRequest is forwarded

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth, oauth-2.0, cors

I am executing an XMLHttpRequest against an API. The API is secured with OAuth authentication against a single provider, and if I call the API from browser and I am not logged in, it automatically forwards me to the provider's login page.

But if I call the API from a web app via XMLHttpRequest in Chrome, I get:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load https://localhost/myapp/api/AppConfig
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-4567890abcdef/oaut…. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

So I guess I have to find out whether I am logged in, and if not, open the login window in a new tab.

But how can I reliably detect that I am not logged in, and that the XMLHttpRequest is forwarded - across all browsers and across all cors settings?

```
try {
    xhr.send(null);
} catch(ex) {
    // how can I find that the issue is with authentication, and not something else?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer; I had something similar with Authorize.net. Two things might be happening:

1. Your firewall is blocking the call.
2. Since you're sending the call with a `null`, the request might think it's a `POST` request and is demanding a header:

`xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Try removing the `null` and leaving `send` empty.

Hope it helps